# how to solve Fatal error: Cannot use [] for reading

Tags: php, arrays

i kept  getting error : Fatal error: Cannot use [] for reading

```
for($m=1; $m<=12; ++$m){
    $monthName=strtolower(date('F', mktime(0, 0, 0, $m, 1)));
<input style='text-align:center' class='form-control ".$monthName."' type='text' size='60' id='".$monthName."' name='".$monthName[]."' value='".$$monthName."'>
}
```

i want to use array [] for input name..how do i fix this

Comment: Put the square brackets outside of the quotes

Comment: I'm hoping this isn't the whole code block, because your syntax is completely off.

Answer (score 2):

You combined the square brackets with the php variable, you should add your square brackets externally with the variable as

```
for($m=1; $m<=12; ++$m){
    $monthName=strtolower(date('F', mktime(0, 0, 0, $m, 1)));
    <input style='text-align:center' class='form-control ".$monthName."' type='text' size='60' id='".$monthName."' name='".$monthName."[]' value='".$$monthName."'>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for($m=1; $m<=12; ++$m){
    $monthName=strtolower(date('F', mktime(0, 0, 0, $m, 1)));
<input style='text-align:center' class='form-control ".$monthName."' type='text' size='60' id='".$monthName."' name='".$monthName."[]' value='".$$monthName."'>
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.